# Getting all variables with a name

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'd like to display each variable created by

```
while (i < document.getElementById("box").value.split("").length) {
 this["numb_" + i] = document.getElementById("box").value.split("")[i];
 i++;
};
```

to display in `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML` to make a result that looks like this in the webpage :
foo + *variable1created* + foo + *variable2created* + foo + *variable3created* etc...
The whole goal is to take numbers from the text box, split the digits, and display each digit separately (means with other text between), all automatically. End result text is loopable.
Here is my codepen so you can take a look at it (I made the code very simple :) here http://codepen.io/ninivert/pen/bdEYqx

Comment: Have you considered using arrays?

Comment: Loop over `this` with a `for...in` loop, and check to see if the key starts with "numb_"

Comment: Yes, I have considered using arrays but I don't know how to create the variable with the arrays already defined... Plus, I need, as I pointed out, to include text between the variable displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Katerina Tort for the help !
Updated the codepen to contain answer.

http://codepen.io/ninivert/pen/bdEYqx

```
function myFunction() {
 var i = 0;
  while (i < document.getElementById("box").value.split("").length) {
        this["numb_" + i] = document.getElementById("box").value.split("")[i];
i++;
};
fillText();
}

function fillText(){

 var i = 0;
 var num = this["numb_" + i];
 var result = '';
 while (!!num) {
  console.log(num)
  result += process(num);
  num = this["numb_" + (++i)];
 }

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = result;
}

function process(num) {
  return 'foo' + num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
var i = 0;
var num = this["numb_" + i];
while (!!num) {
 process(num);
 num = this["numb_" + (++i)];
};
```

Comment: How can I use that in the code ? Do I have to replace that with the original variable creator ? I've included a codepen, please show me how to use your script. Or even paste the modified javascript in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, but i don't really understand what your code does, it's very long and i can't figure out the purpose of it. you asked how you can find all objects [numb_*] like from this, i wrote you a snippet)

Comment: Here you go, http://codepen.io/ninivert/pen/bdEYqx/. I need the `<p id="text">RESULT</p>` to display all the variables created, with strings between the variables so the result looks like this : foo + [numb_0] + foo + [numb_1] + foo + [numb_2] etc...

Comment: sorry for holding you on this topic, but do you know if it is possible to treat the last variable differently ? I want to substract the last variable (so the last digit) to 10. If yes, how ?

Comment: after the while() cycle, this["numb_" + (i-1)] would be the last number